# To find jordan canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra

Which of the following matrices have Jordan canonical form of equal to the $3\times 3$ matrix

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

a)$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

b)$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

c)$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

d)$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Here characteristic equation of the matrix is $x^3$.Hence the 3 eigenvalues of the matrix are zero.
Do we want to find the eigenvalues of all the matrices in the options?Is there any other way?

Comment: A friendly note, you can check out [this page here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to properly format mathematics on this site.  In doing so, your matrices can look like $\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @jgon great edit.  As a matter of efficiency, however, note that `\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}` will work; I find this to be quicker than the whole "begin/end" deal.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Wow thanks so much for that, I had no idea, that will help so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finding the eigenvalues of any of these matrices is not particularly difficult; they are all upper-triangular.

**Hint:** Suppose that $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix with zero as its only (complex) eigenvalue.  Note that $A$ has the desired J-C form if and only if $A \neq 0$ but $A^2 = 0$ (why?).

Answer (score 1):

The given Jordan canonical form implies, minimal polynomial of corresponding matrix should be $x^2=0.$ Hence if matrix $A$ is having the property that $A \neq 0$ and $A^2=0 ,$ it will have desired Jordan canonical form.